# Python module for playing lots of mp3 files together

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I was searching but couldn't find a good python module that allows me to load lots of sounds and play them the time I want, some of them together. Like:
I have like 10 mp3 files, some of them are sample dubstep files, so I want to create a music with them. Then I need to load them fast, not load file by file every time I wanna play it. So I need a module that can load lots of sounds with a 'for' condition and then create a 'object' for each sound, and then play it anytime I want.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a synth-like to play sound effects with one click -- which plenty of programs already do. (For example, [GarageBand](http://www.macworld.com/article/1136990/gbsoundeffects.html) on the Mac)

Comment: No, I want it because I'm doing a hardware interface that ables me to play these sounds

Comment: Playing sound is beyond the scope of the Python core library, so the answer will be OS-specific. What OS are you using?

Comment: Take a look at [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Snack Sound Toolkit](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/), which is multiplatform:

```
sound = Sound() 
sound.read('sound.mp3') 
sound.play()
```

Then just use different .read() + .play() combos based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a module that can load lots of sounds with a 'for' condition and then create a 'object' for each sound

As [@Aya suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000135/python-module-for-playing-lots-of-mp3-files-together#comment22842934_16000135) you could use [`pyglet`](http://pyglet.org/download.html) (+ [`AVbin`](http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Download.html) for mp3) to play several mp3 files in parallel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import random
from glob import glob

import pyglet 

# load sounds    
paths = glob(os.path.expanduser('~/Music/*.mp3'))
sounds = [pyglet.media.load(p, streaming=False) for p in paths]

# play them in parallel
for sound in sounds:
    player = sound.play()
    player.volume = random.random()
    player.push_handlers(on_eos=lambda: print('done playing the sound'))

# exit in `delay` seconds
pyglet.clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: pyglet.app.exit(), delay=10)
# run event loop
pyglet.app.run()
```

It works on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux. It supports both Python 2 and 3 (pyglet 1.2).